# Accessing data in other Method

Tags: c#

I passed some data from one form to another form. It's ok. but I can't accessed same data from another method in same form. This is the code (i.e :- StDate,EndDate......SDEvening are my data which I passed from an other form.

```
public frmLeaveRequestConfirmation(DateTime StDate, DateTime EndDate, string SDFull, Boolean SDMorning, Boolean SDEvening)
{
    //I can Access those data(StDate,EndDateSDFull......) from here
}

private void RequestLeave()
{
    blLeaveManagement bl = new blLeaveManagement();
    dalLeaveManagement dal = new dalLeaveManagement();
    dal.MyProperty_Exception = "";

    dal.MyProperty_LvStartDate = //I want to equal this to StDate;
}
```

I want to eqaul dal.MyProperty_LvStartDate to StDate. but i can't access to StDate from RequestLeave() method. please somebody give me a solution.

Comment: frmLeaveRequestConfirmation should return variables...

Comment: How do you call RequestLeave method!! it is better to make it take an argument with the value that you need to use inside it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a variable to store `StDate`, **outside** of your method:

```
DateTime stDate;
public frmLeaveRequestConfirmation(DateTime StDate, DateTime EndDate, string SDFull, Boolean SDMorning, Boolean SDEvening)
{
   stDate = StDate;
   ...
}
```

Then you can access it from your `RequestLeave` method.

```
dal.MyProperty_LvStartDate = stDate;
```

Comment: I think there should be better way to do this rather than just creating variable, don't you agree